# Unity 3D Cannot drag prefabs from project folder to scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

On Unity 5.3.4f1 when I try to drag any prefab (for example the standard asset FPSController prefab) from my Project folder onto the scene or Hierchay I get no response.

The prefab isn't placed and my cursor stays in pointer mode throughout.

This happens to me on all sample and new projects with and without an empty scene.

My Unity is on a MacBook Pro running El Capitan 10.11.3

Comment: @JoeBlow I think it is typo. 't' is close to '5' on qwerty keyboard. So it is Unity3D 5.3.

Comment: oh of course, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened with me sometimes, one way to solve this is to create a empty prefab manually. In case you don't know how to do it

```
 GameObjects -> Create Prefab
```

Tell me if it helps.

Comment: Thanks I just went back on after reading your answer and it just works now so I'll expect it to do that occasionally in the future thanks.